# DisplayName set to "__Standard Value" on Renderings

Tags: presentation

I have a very strange issue in this Solution I'm working on 8.* that all Renderings suddenly have "__Standard Values" as Displayname and I can't get rid of it. 
And some of them also have EN & DK versions.. Help?!

Has anyone ever seen this behavior before and know how to fix it ?

The result is that XE is totally unusable as all components is named "__Standart Value" :(

Comment: just as a initial suggestion, did you try removing displayName value from those rendering items ?

Comment: Try searching in the database directly for the "_Standard values" string

Comment: @scFootsteps I tried that and also tried SPE and that seemed to work but then it didn't.